# A quicker way to do a Lagrange multiplier problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I was working on the problem: minimize $x + 4z$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 2 $.  I have it solved, I want a faster method for use in standardized exams.

### My work:

I tackled this using Lagrange Multipliers, considering the interior by looking for points where all individual partial derivatives of $x+ 4z$ are zero, (of which there are none).  Then considering the boundary

$$ (x + 4z) - \lambda ( x^2 + y^2 +z^2 - 2) $$

From here I differentiated w.r.t x,y,z, $\lambda$ and set equal to 0 to yield

$$ 1 - 2\lambda x = 0 \rightarrow 1 = 2\lambda x $$ 
$$ - 2 \lambda y = 0  \rightarrow 0 = 2 \lambda y \rightarrow y=0$$
$$ 4 - 2 \lambda z = 0 \rightarrow 4 = 2\lambda z$$
$$  - (x^2 + y^2 +z^2  -2 ) = 0  \rightarrow x^2 +z^2 = 2$$

Looking at equations 1, 3 we have

$$ \frac{1}{2} = \lambda x, 2 = \lambda z $$ And therefore

$$ \frac{1}{4} + 4 = \lambda^2 (x^2 +z^2 ) = 2 \lambda ^2 $$

$$ \frac{17}{8} = \lambda ^2 $$

And thus $$ \lambda = \pm \sqrt{ \frac{17}{8} } $$

$x = \frac{1}{2\lambda}, z = \frac{2}{\lambda} $

Yields

$$ x + 4z = \frac{1}{2\lambda} + 4 \frac{2}{\lambda} = \frac{17}{2 \lambda} 
 = \pm \sqrt{17} \sqrt{2} = \pm \sqrt{34}$$

Clearly $-\sqrt{34}$ is smaller, so we opt for that as our solution.

Now while this works, and makes sense, its not satisfactory as it TAKES SO LONG. And on a Math GRE where the expectation is to do this under 30 seconds a problem, I was hoping there was a faster method. Any suggestions? [Also open to ways to speed up the process, since even the same method with a different angle might be superior]

Comment: You could do it a bit faster by noting that it cannot be optimal to have $y \neq 0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$|x + 4z| \le \sqrt{1^2 + 4^2} \sqrt{x^2+z^2} \le \sqrt{34}.$$
Then think about when Cauchy-Schwarz attains equality.

Comment: Equality is attained when the $(1, 4)$ and $(x,z)$ vectors are linearly dependent, (of course thats easily possible using rescaling), there exists a $c$ such that $(c)^2 + (4c)^2 = 2$ and during that time we have a hard equality. Now how to argue about signs? How do we know that the negative solution is present, and it isn't just the positive

Comment: I guess at that point, just think about the fact its a circle. This makes sense